# Highly Available DB with consistent hashing P2P design

Tags: database-design, high-availability

I am learning about HA DBs

https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/highly-available-database/

According to the above, here is how writes/reads happen in this system

Write request:

> A client can contact any node in the ring with a put() request to write data,
> this node acts as a coordinating node for this request. Coordinating node then forwards
> the request to the mapping nodes for the data(hashing) and waits for acknowledgement from them.
> When it receives W(explained later) acknowledgements, it returns a write-accepted message to the client.

Read request:

> To perform a get() request, client can connect to any node in the ring which becomes the coordinating node
> for this request. The coordinating node then asks all replica nodes for this data and returns consolidated
> data to the client when R of them replies back.

Read and Write consistency:

> W and R are called write and read consistency number respectively. To recap, W is the minimum number of nodes from which the coordinating node should get an ack before making a write successful and R is the minimum number of nodes from which the coordinating node should get back read values to return them back to the client.
>
> R & W together forms quorum of the system. For a read to be consistent(return the latest write), we need to keep **W + R > P**.
>
> Depending on the feature requirement W and R can be adjusted, for example to have very fast writes we can keep **W = 1** and **R = P**. If our system is read heavy we can keep **R = 1** and **W = P**. If read and write are equally distributed, we can keep both **R and W as (P+1)/2**.

Can all the shards/nodes on the consistent hashing ring act as mapping, replica and coordinating nodes ? Can the mapping logic exist on the nodes on the ring ? How do we decide which node a client gets to contact ?